# SQL connection fails when assembly compiled for x86

Tags: .net, sql-server, .net-assembly

I'm experiencing a problem with .net 3.5 sp1 application that is connecting to a sql server using SQLClient.

If I compile the application as "Any CPU" everything works fine, however if I compile the application as x86 the following error is given:

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"

I have verified this with a simple testapplication compiled in 2 different modes.

The real application of course needs to be compiled as x86 because of COM/ActiveX dependencies.

The server the application running on is Server2008 and the SQLserver 2008 is installed on a different server.

Does the x86 SQLClient assembly behave differently than the x64?

Any help would be appreciated, I just killed a full day trying to figure this out...

Comment: do you connect vis DSN by the chance?

Comment: I have tried using dns, computername, IP-adress.
Same result, "AnyCPU" works and x86 fails

Comment: You need to really check that you compile x86 and "Any CPU". Make sure that your configuration name (x86, Any CPU) has the same "Target CPU". Then, make sure that in your Build->configuration Manager, your project is compiled to Platform x86. Some people don't understand that if all these 3 items are not configured properly, you might build solution for anyCPU, your project set for x86 platform but it generated x64 code. One needs to be aware that it might say x86 but produce x64. Make sure you get all those correct.

Comment: but this problem looks to me more like DSN problem. On 64 bit boxes there are two different ODBC providers and it seems that it channels through a wrong one. Is your hardware 64bit?